# Android - RecyclerView is loading slowly with small data

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, adapter

H, I am developing an application that display all video on list. I got problem when loading list to RecyclerView, all item on list be tiny on 1,2 seconds before fill out all data, like image below:

- List item

[image: First, it display almost item but it's small and not fill data]

- After 1,2 seconds:

[image]

- This is my adapter:

> ```
> @Override
> public void onBindViewHolder(final MostPopularByCountryAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
>   // fetch data to UI
>   holder.order.setText(String.valueOf(position + 1));
>   holder.name.setText(mListVideo.get(position).getTitle());
>   Picasso.with(mContext).load(mListVideo.get(position).getThumbnailsHigh().getUrl()).into(holder.videoThumbnail);
>   holder.duration.setText(UtilitySupport.convertDuration(mListVideo.get(position).getDuration().trim()));
>
>   boolean isFavour = dataPreferences.getBookmarkVideo(mListVideo.get(position).getVideoId());
>   mListVideo.get(position).setFavourite(isFavour);
>   final VideoStorageEntity storageEntity = new VideoStorageEntity();
>   storageEntity.setVideoId(mListVideo.get(position).getVideoId());
>   storageEntity.setFavourite(isFavour);
>   storageEntity.setThumbnailsHighUrl(mListVideo.get(position).getThumbnailsHigh().getUrl());
>   storageEntity.setTitle(mListVideo.get(position).getTitle());
>
>   // setting 3 button action //
>   // favourite event
>   holder.viewLike.setOnStateChangeListener(true, mListVideo.get(position).isFavourite(), new OnStateChangeListener() {
>       @Override
>       public void onSelectedChange(boolean isSelected) {
>           if (isSelected) {
>               holder.isLike.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_love_press);
>               dataPreferences.saveBookmarkVideo(storageEntity);
>           } else {
>               holder.isLike.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_love_white);
>               dataPreferences.removeBookmarkVideo(storageEntity);
>           }
>           mListVideo.get(position).setFavourite(isSelected);
>       }
>   });
>   if (mListVideo.get(position).isFavourite()) {
>       holder.isLike.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_love_press);
>   } else {
>       holder.isLike.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_love_white);
>   }
> }
> ```

Comment: does the data in mListVideo is coming from a server?

Comment: You're loading video data, almost certainly from a server, repeatedly.  Yeah, that's never going to work well.

Comment: I forgot to add placeholder. Louis Nguyen suggest me. thank guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Picasso.with(mContext).load(mListVideo.get(position).getThumbnailsHigh().getUrl()).into(holder.videoThumbnail);
```

This line code will get image from server and will delay until image get successful. You should set place-holder image for Picasso.

```
Picasso.with(mContext).load(mListVideo.get(position).getThumbnailsHigh().getUrl()).placeholder(R.drawable.your_resource).into(holder.videoThumbnail);
```